# How can I simplfy algebraic expressions involving algebraic identities in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have given expressions and I need to simplify them to their normal form i.e. there should not be any algebraic identities.

Algebraic identities for reference as follows.

> X+0 = X
>   X+0 = X
>   X*1 = X
>   X*0 = 0
>   X/1 = X
>   0/X = 0
>   X-X = 0
>   X+X = 2X
>   X\X = 1

Sample expression and it's expected output are as follows,

> Example 1:
>   Given expression:   (X*(Y/Y)-X)*X
>   Simplified expression: 0
>
> Example 2:
>   Given expression: ((X+X)/X)*(Y+Y-Y)
>   Simplified expression: 2*Y
>
> Example 3:
>   Given expression: (A*B/1)*(C+1-C)
>   Simplified expression: A*B

My doubt is how can I represent any variable such as X or Y and perform this identities in prolog for this simplification.

There is no restriction on Input form or output form.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question, because the algebraic identities you show are **insufficient** to derive the examples you show.

For example, let us consider the subterm **`Y/Y`**, which occurs in your first example.

Can you use any of the algebraic identities you show to simplify this term?

**Answer**: No.
**Exercise**: Why not?

You may be tempted to add the "identity" `X/X = 1` to your identities, but that would render the identities **incorrect**. This means that you would be able to derive identities that obviously *do not hold*.

To see this, consider the term `0/0`, which you could reduce:

- via `0/X` → `0`
- *and* via `X/X` → `1`

thus *incorrectly* obtaining `0 = 1` from these identities.

For more information about this interesting topic, read about **term rewriting systems** (TRS).

Comment: yes you are right, I forgot to add that identity and may be  many more for that matter.
What if I add that, than How can I express this in prolog?